# Looking at Percent Change of Count per user

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a problems that i've been wrestling with withs some time. I have a messy data frame I've managed to re-arrange into this format.

```
user_id  date     n
user1    1-1-15   60
user1    1-2-15   25
user1    1-5-15   20
user2    1-2-15   23
user2    1-4-15   15
user3    2-12-15  9
...      ...      ...
```

The user start and end dates don't all sync up and some aren't continuous.  Ideally I'd like to find a percent change for each user over their lifetime. Something like:

```
user_id delta
user1   -%15
user2   -%27
user3    0%
...      ...
```

any help would be awesome.

Comment: may be `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(user_id) %>% summarise(delta= 10*first(n)/(last(n)-first(n)))`

Comment: That definitely works thanks! Though the data is skewed heavily by the first and last values. Is there any alternative, similar to finding the slope of a best fit line through the data?

Comment: Do you need `?lm` by group

Comment: Not sure what you really wanted. Perhaps `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, if(.N>1) coef(lm(n~date))[2] else 0 , user_id]` or the equivalent data.table solution for the above is `setDT(df1)[, list(delta=if(.N>1) 10*n[1L]/(n[.N]-n[1L]) else 0), user_id]`

Comment: In that case, you can use `base R` options `sapply(split(df1, df1$user_id), function(x) if(nrow(x)>1) coef(lm(n~date, data=x))[2] else 0)`

Comment: Managed to install and run both of the data.table solutions, but getting the following error:   object 'user_id' not found

Comment: yep works fine thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the `dplyr` option to find the change of `last` versus `first` 'n', grouped by the 'user_id' would be

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  summarise(delta= 10*first(n)/(last(n)-first(n)))
```

Similar option using `data.table` will be to convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), group by  the 'user_id', we create the 'delta' column by calculating the change of last 'n' (`n[.N]`) with respect to first (`n[1L]`). We can also have a `if/else` to condition to return the calculated value if the number of elements within the group is greater than 1 (`.N >1`) or `else` to return 0.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(delta=if(.N>1) 10*n[1L]/(n[.N]-n[1L]) else 0), by = user_id]
```

---

Suppose if we need to do the `lm` for each 'user_id', we can get the `slope` within the `do` environment.  Just like in the previous case, we can create an `if/else` condition to return slope value if the number of elements is greater than 1 or else to return 0.

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(user_id) %>%
   mutate(N= n()) %>%
   do(data.frame(slope= if(.$N[1L] >1) coef(lm(.$n~.$date))[2] else 0))
```

Or using `data.table`, we get the `coef` after grouping by 'user_id'

```
setDT(df1)[, if(.N>1) coef(lm(n~date))[2] else 0 , user_id]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(user_id = c("user1", "user1", "user1", "user2", 
"user2", "user3"), date = c("1-1-15", "1-2-15", "1-5-15", "1-2-15", 
"1-4-15", "2-12-15"), n = c(60L, 25L, 20L, 23L, 15L, 9L)),
.Names = c("user_id", 
"date", "n"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```